# using serverside regular expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am validating website by writing serverside regular expression when i copy the same
 thing in javascript and try to validate its not happening a part of my code is as follows

```
"^(https://)+\w+\.+\w" - //serverside validation working fine
document.getElementById('txtWebsite').value.match("^(https://)+\w+\.+\w") == null
```

how can i implement the same in client side validation

Comment: tag this question as javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String.match is considering you regex as String and not as a RegExp object.
Try this:

```
document.getElementById('txtWebsite').value.match(/^(https:\/\/)+\w+\.+\w/)
```